# "Study at class 5C" or "study in class 5C"

Tags: prepositions

I'm writing an essay. And I would like to know which one is correct.

> I am studying **at** class 5C

or

> I am studying **in** class 5C

Comment: Has the "C"  in "Class 5C" any effect on the grade that you are learning ? My suggestion would be: "I am attending the fifth class at the x-school in y-town.

Comment: I'm a Vietnamese, and in Vietnam, we divide each grade into different classes, like 5A, 5B, 5C,... I think the C in the class's name doesn't have any effect on the grade. It's only name.

Answer (score 1):

I attended an elementary school in that similarly divided its students into classes designated by grade level and letter, with each combination also corresponding to a specific [homeroom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeroom) teacher and to a specific classroom. Whether you would use *in* or *at* would depend on whether you were referring to the grouping or to the physical location within the school building.

*[At](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/at)* generally refers to a specific location, whereas *[in](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/in_1)* can refer to a location as well as to membership in something. As such, *in* is the most likely scenario, although which meaning is intended would depend on context:

> I am in 5C. (*I am enrolled in the group of students which is designated 5C*. In the U.S., one would more commonly use the homeroom teacher's name: *I am in Mrs. Smith's fifth-grade class*)
>
> I am in 5C. (*I am physically located inside the room labeled 5C*)

While you would use *at* to indicate enrollment at a particular institution (*I studied at the University of Alberta*; *the children are in elementary school at St. Ann's*), you would not normally use *at* with an individual section within that institution. You could use it if referring to the physical classroom as a point in space:

> I am at 5C. (*I am physically located somewhere close enough to the room labeled 5C that I would cite it as the nearest reference point, and I am not necessarily inside it*)

Answer (score -1):

I am attending the fifth class at the (Name of school) in (Name of city).

"attend or attending" is a very common and formal way to say that someone is a member of a class, visiting a school or other occasions like a meeting etc...

Except the "C" in "Class 5C" has no effect on the grade that you are learning.

[Cambridge Dictionary: attend](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/attend)